# how to uninstall Linux dual boot with Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

I installed Kali Linux (Debian distro) dual boot with Windows 7 but there were some damages with the ISO file i downloaded so Kali didn't install correctly, 
please how do I uninstall Kali dual boot with Windows?and how to completly uninstall grub?i mean when I boot my PC computer directly boots into Windows cuz i'm gonna redownload the ISO file and reinstall Kali on my PC Thank you in advance

Comment: Kali is not Ubuntu. It's offtopic here I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Windows partition manager and delete the partition where you installed Linux and then format it. Start fresh installation.

Comment: well I actually already tried to delete the Linux partiton with diskmgmt.msc but when rebooting the PC rescue_grub appears and says no such partition when I trype rescue_grub>help an error occurs i couldn't log in to windows so i had to get the linux DVD and reinstall it so i can log in to windows